# Codeigniter $query->list_fields() not working if db query cache is enabled

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I just wonder, why the $query->list_fields() method throws an empty array if i enable the DB query caching.This is actually a Codeigniter Method to get query fields names.

But at the same time, It works fine if i do not enable db query caching. This issue is also in Windows server, so i believe Environment doesn't matter at all.

Also, i have checked with MySQL native function "mysqli_fetch_field" to get field name in both server (Linux and Windows). It works fine. So i believe the issue only with Db query caching.

For your information, I am using Codeigniter Version 3.

Ref: [Codeigniter $this->list_fields](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/fields.html)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676279/codeigniter-list-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from documentation:

**Not All Database Functions Work with Caching**

Lastly, we need to point out that the result object that is cached is a simplified version of the full result object. For that reason, some of the query result functions are not available for use.

The following functions ARE NOT available when using a cached result object:

```
num_fields()
field_names()
field_data()
free_result()
```

Also, the two database resources (result_id and conn_id) are not available when caching, since result resources only pertain to run-time operations.